# Get full package module name

Tags: python, inspect

For verbose debug messages in my application I'm using a function that returns a helpful prefix. Consider the following example:

```
import inspect

def get_verbose_prefix():
    """Returns an informative prefix for verbose debug output messages"""
    s = inspect.stack()
    module_name = inspect.getmodulename(s[1][1])
    func_name = s[1][3]

    return '%s->%s' % (module_name, func_name)

def awesome_function_name():
    print "%s: Doing some awesome stuff right here" % get_verbose_prefix()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    awesome_function_name()
```

This outputs:

```
test->awesome_function_name: Doing some awesome stuff right here
```

---

**My issue is:** When I have a module in a package, for instance 'myproject.utilities.input', the module name returned from `get_verbose_prefix` is still just 'input', not 'myproject.utilities.input'. This drastically reduces the helpfulness of the prefix in large projects when there can be several 'input' modules in different submodules all working together.

**So my question is:** Is there a simple way of retrieving the full module name within it's package in Python? I'm planning on expanding the `get_verbose_prefix` function to check for '__init__.py' files in the parent directories of the module to extrapolate it's full name, but first I'd like to know if there's an easier way to do it.

Comment: Note: in the context of Python packaging, "package name" ≠ "import path". Packages can contain modules and namespaces that aren't necessarily named after the package itself.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`__name__` always contains the full name of the module. (Other than `__main__` on main, of course.)

Comment: I suppose that's true, but how do I get to the actual module from the context of my prefix function?

Comment: Never mind, I figured that out: `inspect.getmodule(s[1][0]).__name__`. Also you should edit in that `__name__` doesn't actually always return the full name of the module since it returns `__main__` on the executed module

Comment: What is `s` in `inspect.getmodule(s[1][0]).__name__`?

Comment: @QuentinRoy `s = inspect.stack()`

Comment: That feeling when a [buried comment by the questioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705055/python-get-full-package-module-name#comment15525398_11705103) answers the question better than any of the actual answers.

Answer (score 8):

Try using the `__name__` attribute of the module.

Answer (score 5):

the other answers don't account for `__name__` becoming `__main__` for the program entry point or don't handle it properly.

this works for me:

```py
def python_module() -> str:
    stack = inspect.stack()
    module = inspect.getmodule(stack[1][0])
    if module is None:
        raise ValueError("module not found")
    res = module.__name__
    if res != "__main__":
        return res
    package = module.__package__
    if package is None:
        package = ""
    mfname = module.__file__
    if mfname is None:
        return package
    fname = os.path.basename(mfname)
    ext = ".py"
    if fname.endswith(ext):
        fname = fname[:-len(ext)]
    if fname == ("__init__", "__main__"):
        return package
    return f"{package}.{fname}"
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple way of retrieving the full module name within its package:

```
print(__file__)
```